# Huawei HMS map kit camera won't move/animate to given position

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

i'm using huawei map kit in my app, i'm following the steps mentioned in their documentation..the map loads and just moves me to ivory coast every time..i don't understand why

my code

```
private HuaweiMap hMap;
    private MapView mMapView;
    double lat;
    double lng;



    private static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        Log.i("TAG", "onCreate");
          Intent i=getIntent();
          double lat=i.getExtras().getDouble("lat");
          double lng=i.getExtras().getDouble("lng");


        mMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        MapsInitializer.setApiKey("the api key");
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        //get map instance
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);


    }

@Override
    public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap map) {

            //get map instance in a callback method
            Log.d("TAG", "onMapReady: ");
            hMap = map;
            hMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            hMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            hMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); //this button doesn't show on screen either

            LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(location,8,2.2f,31.5f);
            hMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            hMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
```

i'm using google maps in the same app (for phones that use gms) and using almost the same approach and everything works perfectly fine with the google map..
please help

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/franalma/MapsWrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

> hMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true) does not take
> effect.

Before using **hMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)**, you need to use **hMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)** to enable the location function on the map.

- Function of **hMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)**: Sets whether to use the location function on the map. (The default value is **false**.)
- Function of **hMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)**: Sets whether to display the my-location icon on the map. (The default value is **true**.)

If **setMyLocationEnabled** is set to **false**, the my-location icon will not be displayed and the location function is unavailable regardless of whether **setMyLocationButtonEnabled** is set. Therefore, you are advised to use **hMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)** to display the my-location icon.

For more information, please refer to [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/huaweimap-0000001050151757-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050151757__section672514559310).

Question 2:

> The map camera always moves to Ivory Coast.

Your usage is correct. You are advised to print relevant longitudes and latitudes to see if they remain unchanged.

In addition, the [moveCamera](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/huaweimap-0000001050151757-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050151757__section168451531308) class is used to directly move the camera, and the [animateCamera](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/huaweimap-0000001050151757-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050151757__section13382161444614) class is used to move the camera through animation. You can use either of the classes to move the camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **animateCamera()**, using this method we can animate the movement of the camera from the current position to the position which we defined.

```
CameraPosition build = new CameraPosition.Builder()
     .target(new LatLng(location.lat, location.lng))
     .zoom(15)
     .bearing(90)
     .tilt(30)
     .build();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(build);
hMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

To know more about maps visit the articles

1. [To customize Maps with Custom Marker and Custom Info Window - Maps Kit](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201345264040690134&fid=0101187876626530001)
2. [Example of Drawing Directions for Driving, Bicycling and Walking - Maps Kit](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201348788492910165&fid=0101187876626530001)